# Different backgrounds on 3 monitor set-up

Tags: compiz, ati, graphics, multiple-monitors, desktop-background

I currently have a 3 monitor set-up using an AMD HD6870 card.  All monitors are 1920 x 1080 and in a 16:9 configuration.  However 2 are orientated as landscape whilst one is in portrait.  The way I have them configured is as a multi-desktop set-up and I am using AMD's Catalyst for this not xinerama.  I wanted to know if it is possible to display separate backgrounds on each monitor, or at the least have the 2 landscape monitors have the same one whilst the portrait monitor has a different one?  Thanks for any help.

Tom

Comment: Did you try the compiz wallpaper plugin? I read that works

Comment: I believe this is to assign different wallpapers to different workspaces and not to each monitor within a workspace.  Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Ah you're right - the solution I had remembered from here https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=98610 worked for dual monitors by just spanning the wallpaper across both displays. I guess you could possibly use a similar approach by stitching your desired images together in the appropriate layout.

Comment: The best way to get this effect is to edit your xorg file (if you use one) by setting a virtual destkop option in your monitors section and giving it a combined area of your three wallpapers added together. You might also need to set the X,Y position for each monitor to get a seamless edge on each screen. This will be much easier assuming your three monitors are the same model, or at least the same aspect ratio